# How can I use var args(variadic arguments) in a function?

Tags: function, variadic-functions, chapel

I tried something like

```
proc foo(args...?n) {
  var x = max(args);
  return x;
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Ege—Thanks for posting this question to SO.  I'd suggest moving the answer that you posted in the question down to the answer section below.  As I understand it, it's reasonable in SO to answer your own question if the Q&A represents something you've figured out and believe others would benefit from (as I believe this would).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I asked the question at the above in the Chapel gitter channel, they gave me the answer at the below. And it worked.

var args actuals can be used as tuples. So unless `max` is a function that takes tuples as args that won’t work. If `max` is also a var args function, you have to pass the elements of tuples one-by-one. However, there is tuple expansion in chapel and the syntax is `(...args)` including the parentheses so the problematic line should be `var x = max((...args))`